# Irrational jQuery slideToggle behavior in dropdown navigation bar

Tags: jquery, navigation, slidetoggle

I'm trying to put together a dropdown navigation bar with jQuery.
Currently my implementation is using inline ul/li with slideToggle. On the li's hover event, I wrote:

```
$(this).find("ul").slideToggle(0.5);
```

However, the problem is, sometimes it works as expected, but sometimes the collapsed menu wouldn't go back. Anybody occured to the same problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $(this).find("ul").each().slideToggle(0.5);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Now the ul dropdown menu doesn't even show! :(

Comment: `each()` needs a callback function as a parameter. In fact, current versions of jQuery will crash your function with a syntax error.